# How can I make my app responsive using only Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, responsive

I have to make a page responsive but they asked me not to use Bootstrap, only Angular Material.

I've been going through the Angular Material documentation a lot and I still can't think of how I could achieve this.

Can anyone give me an idea of ​​how to do it?

Comment: I think that you're asking about angular schematics: https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics, but for make a page responsive you need use media querys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries You can use the well checked media queries from bootstrap or not

Comment: you can use layout: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview to change views to specific view layout(size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not layout components/classes in Angular Material. However, Angular has their own layout library that is commonly used alongside Material - [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API)

It has sm, md, lg, etc modifiers and is based on css flexbox, similar to Bootstrap.

To start, I'd recommend going through the Pages accordion in the right pane, particularly [fxFlex](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API), [fxLayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayout-API), [fxLayoutAlign](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutAlign-API), and [fxLayoutGap](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutGap-API)

Comment: Use Html5 grid and Scss. No media queries needed.